# How to make a Unity navmesh agent keep distance from the target

Tags: unity, c#, navmesh

I want my enemies to follow the player, stop at a certain distance and when enemy is within that distance he will walk away.

```
[SerializeField] Transform target;
[SerializeField] float followRange = 5f;
[SerializeField] float fleeRange = 2f;

NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;
float distToTarget = Mathf.Infinity;

public Animator anim;
[SerializeField] bool hasTarget = false;
[SerializeField] bool hasDanger = false;

void Start()
{
    navMeshAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}

void Update()
{
    distToTarget = Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position);

    if(distToTarget <= followRange && distToTarget >= (fleeRange - 1f))
    {
        hasTarget = true;
    }
    else
    {
        hasTarget = false;
    }

    if(distToTarget <= fleeRange)
    {
        hasDanger = true;
    }
    else
    {
        hasDanger = false;
    }

    if(hasTarget && hasDanger)
    {
        navMeshAgent.SetDestination(transform.position);
    }

    HasTarget();
    HasDanger();
}

void HasTarget()
{
if(hasTarget)
    {
        navMeshAgent.SetDestination(new Vector3 (target.position.x, transform.position.y, target.position.z));
        anim.SetInteger("Status_walk", 1);
    }
    else
    {
        navMeshAgent.SetDestination(transform.position);
        anim.SetInteger("Status_walk", 0);
    }
if(hasDanger){return;}
}

void HasDanger()
{
if(hasDanger)
    {
    Vector3 toTarget = target.position - transform.position;
    if(Vector3.Distance(target.position, transform.position) < fleeRange)
    {
        Vector3 targetPosition = toTarget.normalized * -fleeRange;
        navMeshAgent.SetDestination(targetPosition);
    }
    }
if(hasTarget){return;}
}
```

This code kinda works, but they just walk up to the target, walk away, walk back and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The NavMeshAgent actually has a property [`stoppingDistance`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AI.NavMeshAgent-stoppingDistance.html) that allows you to control the radius around the destination which will cause the agent to consider the target "reached". Unfortunately there is no good way to detect when a NavMeshAgent reached its destination and then react to this event. You can only check if its moving at all, but it could also have stopped because it can't find a valid path.

One simple pattern for implementing AI behaviors in games is the  [state-machine](https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/general-and-gameplay-programming/state-machines-in-games-r2982/). A simple way to implement one is to have:

1. An `enum` with constants representing each state the AI actor can be in.
2. A variable of that type that holds the current state.
3. a `switch`/`case` tree in the Update method which causes the object to behaves differently depending on the current state.

Here is a (abridged and simplified) example from my current project:

```
public class HunterAI : MonoBehaviour {

    private enum State {
        IDLE,
        CHASING_PREY,
        RETURNING_TO_START
    }
    private State currentState = State.IDLE;

    private NavMeshAgent myNavMeshAgent;
    private Vector3 startLocation;

    private Prey chasedPrey;
    [SerializeField] private float preyDetectRadius = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float preyInteractionRadius = 1f;

    

    private void Start() {
        myNavMeshAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        startLocation = transform.position;
    }

    private void Update() {

        switch (currentState) {
            case State.IDLE:
                myNavMeshAgent.destination = startLocation;
                // look for the prey
                var objectsAround = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, preyDetectRadius);
                foreach (var o in objectsAround) {
                    if (o.TryGetComponent<Prey>(out chasedPrey)) {
                        currentState = State.CHASING_PREY;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case State.CHASING_PREY:
                // navigate to prey
                myNavMeshAgent.destination = chasedPrey.transform.position;
                // check if caught
                
                if (myNavMeshAgent.remainingDistance <= preyInteractionRadius) {
                    currentState = State.RETURNING_TO_START;
                }
                break;
            case State.RETURNING_TO_START:
                myNavMeshAgent.destination = startLocation;
                if(myNavMeshAgent.remainingDistance <= 0f) {
                    currentState = State.IDLE;
                }
                break;                    
        }            
    }
```